# Borel-Cantelli-Lemma and almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose it holds: $P(|S_n|> \varepsilon )\leq \frac{1}{2^n \varepsilon^2} $, where $S_n $ is sequence of random variables.

Furthermore it holds: $\sum_{n \geq 1} P[|S_n|> \varepsilon ] <\infty $

An application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that: $P(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |S_n|> \varepsilon )=0$ . Why does this imply $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n=0$ a.s., since I only have $P(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |S_n| \leq \varepsilon )=1$

Comment: It doesn't.  Take $S_n=\epsilon/2$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum P(|S_n| >\frac  1k )<\infty$ for each $k$ . By Borel-Cantelli Lemma $|S_n| \leq \frac 1 k$ for $n$ sufficiently large (or $\lim \sup_n |S_n| \leq \frac  1 k$ ) with probability $1$ (for each $k$) so $S_n \to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Since the right hand side is independent of $n $ I can let $k$ tent to $\infty$  ?

Comment: If $\lim \sup |S_n|\ <\frac 1 k$ for every positive integer $k$ then $\lim \sup  |S_n| =0$ which means $S_n \to 0$.  This has nothing to do with Probability Theory. @Tom

Comment: @Ok thank you, I got it:)